# StaleObjectStateException or OptimisticLockingException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, optimistic-locking

where can I find information on what Exception to catch in a version based optimistic locking save operation.

Texts on "the internet" suggests any of either Hibernate's own or JPA's `OptimisticLockingException`, but as I went for that I see that in my Hibernate 4.3 Session based app this type of Exception comes carried by a `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException`.

The differences of the suggestions makes me wonder what the "real "way to do this is.

Also, I have prepared moving from Hibernate Session to JPA. Is there a standard on this issue (of mine)? What would that be?

Cheers
Mats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the API you are going to use.

1. If you use JPA and the `EntityManager` interface then Hibernate will simply wrap the all `[StaleStateException][1]` (which is a base class of `StaleObjectStateException`) in a [javax.persistence.OptimisticLockingException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OptimisticLockException.html)
2. If you use the Hibernate specific API through the `Session` interface then you'll get the `StaleObjectStateException` instead.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the information, Vlad. Strange that I couldn't find that out for myself.